# FileCopyUtils do Spring Com comportamento estranho

Tags: java, spring

não sei se alguém aqui usa o **FileCopyUtils** oferecido pelo **Spring**, mas estou usando em um método de replicação de imagens em meu sistema. Ele Tem como objetivo "pegar" as imagens que se encontram na pasta temp do meu sistema e replicar para outro ligar no servidor. Abaixo está o método com alguns comentários:

```
public Set<Image> imageReplication(String destination) throws IOException {
    Set<Image> img = new HashSet<>();
    Image image =null;
    try {
        List<ImageJson> imagePathTmpList = dashboardFacade.getImagePathTmpList();

        Gson gson = null;

        String subdomain = dashboardFacade.getAgency().getSubdomain();
        File base = new File("/home/manolo/joocebox-img/" + subdomain + "/"+ destination);


        for (ImageJson imageJsonList : imagePathTmpList) {
            gson = new Gson();
            image = new Image();

            FileMeta imgTmp = gson.fromJson(imageJsonList.getJson(), FileMeta.class);
            //Caminho antigo do arquivo
            String oldPath = imgTmp.getFileTmpPath();

                        //Novo caminho concatenando o nome do arquivo.
            String newPath = base + "/" + imgTmp.getFileName();

            //Verifica se o diretorio base exesti, caso não ele cria o caminho e faz a copia dos arquivos. Creio que aqui que dispare a exeption.
            if(!base.exists()){
                base.mkdirs();
                FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(oldPath), new FileOutputStream(newPath));
            }else{
                FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(oldPath), new FileOutputStream(newPath));
            }

            image.setJson(newPath);
            img.add(image);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        deleteTmp();
    }

    return img;
}
```

Bem, pessoal problema é que na hora da verificação se meu caminho base existe na maquina e na realização da cpia dos arquivos ele dispara a **exeption** **FileNotFoundException**. Mas engraçado que na minha maquina o comportamento é normal. agora quando é executado no servidor essa exceção e disparada.

Gostaria de saber se vocês concordam com minha logica e se caso estou errando em algo.

Abraço!

---

EDITANDO:

Abaixo encontra-se a saida do `System.out.println(base.getAbsolutePath())`
como o stackTrace:

```
/home/ubuntu/joocebox-img/manolo/Novo Destino
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ubuntu/joocebox-img/manolo/Novo Destino/FotoMinha.jpg (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at br.com.joocebox.controller.FileController.imageReplication(FileController.java:161)
    at br.com.joocebox.controller.FileController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$282cc946.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at br.com.joocebox.controller.FileController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e30b112a.imageReplication(<generated>)
    at br.com.joocebox.controller.DestinationController.addDestination(DestinationController.java:108)
    at br.com.joocebox.controller.DestinationController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$49da9f7c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at br.com.joocebox.controller.DestinationController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$289546a0.addDestination(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: O `path` é esse mesmo no servidor: `/home/manolo/joocebox-img/` ? Sugiro colocar uns `System.out.println()` para ver os paths e onde está o erro.

Comment: Oi  Kyllopardiun, na verdade uso a amazon logo o path  é /home/ubuntu. Mas o joocebox-img não existe, por esse motivo coloquei o mkdirs() e logo depois disso fazer a copia. O que me intriga é que ja debuguei varias vezes aqui na minha maquina local e tudo me parece correto. Obrigado

Comment: Achei que meu base.mkdirs(); faria a verificação e caso a pasta não exista ele logo tomava a responsabilidade de criar. O mais estranho que mesmo não tendo a pasta criada na minha maquina o mkdirs realiza tal criação sem disparar a exceção. Será que eu que estou cometendo algum equivoco e ainda não estou enxergando?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque todo o  `StackTrace();` e também o valor de `System.out.println(base.getAbsolutePath())`. Se quiser posso responder com a forma de criar o `mkdir recursivo` mas não tenho como garantir que irá resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Então @Kyllopardiun teria que fazer o deploy da aplicação e rodar aqui. Geralmente é um pouco demorado, se vocÊ puder me adintar como fazer a forma recursiva fico muito grato. Quando eu estiver com o stackTrace na mão eu posto para você dar uma olhada. Obrigado!

Comment: pode ser os espaços em branco teste sem os mesmos e verifique o resultado.

Comment: Testeiuma string sem espaços e o problema ainda ocorre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente criar de forma recursiva o `Path` para o diretório que irá trabalhar:

Troque onde está o base.mkdirs() por:

```
    if (!base.exists()) {
        criaPath(base);
    }
```

Método recursivo para criar o `Path`:

```
/**
 * @param d o diretório a ser criado (recusivamente)
 */
public void criaPath(File d) {
    //verifica se o diretório acima existe (proteger o código contra erros)
    if (!d.getParentFile().exists()) {
        criaPath(d.getParentFile());
    }
    d.mkdir();
}
```

Comment: Legal! Vou tentar utilizar sua proposta e te informo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda até agora :)

Comment: Então Kyllopardium, implementei a solução como você descreu acima e mesmo assim continua a disparar a mesma exceção. É totalmente estranho, pois em minha maquina funciona perfeitamente. Alguma sugestão? Obrigado pela atenção.